# How to change default language of UIActionSheet buttons?

Tags: localization, ios5, uiactionsheet

In an iOS5 app, I have a UITextView with data detectors for phone numbers and so on. When I tap the underlined link / detected data, everything works as expected, but when I tap that link a little longer, an UIActionSheet appears (Call xyz, Add to Contacts and so on). This is fine as well except the language of those buttons English but it should be German. I already set the default language of the app to German in xcode and also deleted the English localization but the button titles remain as they are. Is it possible to change the language somehow?

Comment: Is your device language set to German (in the Settings App)?

Comment: Yes, it is set both in the device and the simulator and the result is the same for both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer myself. Originally, I thought I need to have the English localization because when I deleted the (only one) localization, the storyboard file was deleted as well. The solution now was very simple. I added the German localization (the storyboard is copied) and then deleted the English one. This way the action sheet buttons are German now and the storyboard file remains in the project - problem solved.

Sorry for being too stupid to try this before :-/